# Can I access compile flags from within ActionScript 2/3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

Is it possible to access compile time flags (in specifics: the allow debugging flag) in ActionScript?

If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can access the -debug flag directly. What I usually do when compiling with mxmlc is add a custom parameter which is available in ActionScript.

Add this to the parameters you use with mxmlc `-define=CONFIG::debug,true` and in the ActionScript code you can just go ahead and write something like this:

```
if(CONFIG::debug) {
    // -- DO SOME STUFF IF WE'RE DEBUGGING
}
```

With this technique you can add a bunch of custom conditional compilation parameters if you want. In addition, anything left inside the `CONFIG::debug` block will not actually be compiled into the SWF if you set `CONFIG::debug, false`

Here's a good start http://www.boostworthy.com/blog/?p=227 and here's the Adobe Flex 3 doc on the subject: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, it does what I want. I'll leave the question open for a day to see if anyone else comes up with a better plan (like directly being able to find out the -debug flag) and if not pick your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: @ikanobori Sounds good, I'm interested in knowing that myself but haven't found/seen any way of doing it. The closest I've seen in ActionScript itself is `Capabilities.isDebugger` which lets you know it the player itself is a debug version; which actually doesn't do much good. :/